# Create discrete SeekBar programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Creating a discrete SeekBar in Android in a layout file works fine, SeekBar object is visible and can be used programmatically after having been inflated from the layout file:

```
<SeekBar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/seekbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"/>
```

But I need to create the discrete SeekBar programmatically, WITHOUT inflating it from a layout file.

So I tried:

```
AppCompatSeekBar seekBar = new AppCompatSeekBar(context, null, R.style.Base_Widget_AppCompat_SeekBar_Discrete);
```

This does NOT work. seekBar does not show and keeps invisible, whatever I try and whatever LayoutParameters I use.

Creating a non discrete SeekBar, however, works fine, seekBar is visible and can be used:

```
AppCompatSeekBar seekBar = new AppCompatSeekBar(context);
```

What am I doing wrong when creating a discrete SeekBar programmatically?

Comment: Are you having a dark style ? if so, then try moving to light style either in app or in system or both

Comment: Sorry, but changing to light style does not change things in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `ContextThemeWrapper` and apply the style as a Theme. Then you have to pass this into the `AppCompatSeekBar` constructor with the `defStyleAttr` to be 0.

**Example:**

```
//get your parent View Group
RelativeLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.parentRoot);
//Use a ContextThemeWrapper and setup your style as a Theme
ContextThemeWrapper wrappedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, com.google.android.material.R.style.Base_Widget_AppCompat_SeekBar_Discrete);
//initialize AppCompatSeekBar using the above ContextThemeWrapper
AppCompatSeekBar seekBar = new AppCompatSeekBar(wrappedContext, null, 0);
//set to the seekBar your LayoutParams eg: (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
seekBar.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
seekBar.setMax(10);
//finally add it to your parent View Group
parent.addView(seekBar);
```

**Result:**

[image: seekbar]